# Does epoll give available bytes to read or write, and threshold feature?

Tags: socket

kqueue gives available bytes to send or receive if file descriptior (such as socket) gets signal. and, kqueue gives threshold feature, for example, it does not signal until sufficient bytes are available to read or write if user wants.

Are these two features also given by epoll? I googled for it but I couldn't find them yet.

Comment: I strongly suspect it doesn't...

Comment: Very unlikely. Kqueue allows to override per-socket low watermark. Linux supports low watermark (see socket(7), SO_RCVLOWAT) but in broken way, according to my manpage: it's used on reading but not on polling, so polling give false positives. Avoid to use it.

Comment: Thank you all. Intention for these two features is to minimize calling count of send() or recv() and preventing worker thread from becoming idle state. Is there any alternative way of achieving this intention?